# Will Canon lens work with a7s II?

Tags: camera, lenses

Will this [lens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007Y794O) work with the Sony A7s II.

So I am learning which lenses can be used with my new camera. Basically I am looking for a relatively inexpensive zoom lens. I understand that the lens has to not only be e mount but also needs a full frame lens.

Eventhough this lens is canon, will it work with my Sony camera with an adapter. Will the frame be cropped? (I am looking at the Fotodoix adapter). Also will Image Stablization work at all?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FWIW, I have this lens and like it very much. Good luck!

Comment: Have you used it with a7s? How is the IS?

Comment: I've not used it with a Sony, only an older Canon Rebel and a Canon 7D. I find the IS to be pretty nice. I feel like I can get an extra stop or 2 out of it with the IS in many cases. I like that you can choose to stabilize along only 1 axis or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah yes, Canon lenses are a lot cheaper it seems than Sony lenses. With the A7s ii you an use both APS-C and FF (full frame) lenses. With an APS-C lens you have to enable APS-C mode in the camera and it will result in a crop, and in my experience, a slightly noticeable drop in quality/sharpness especially in low light. That being said, APS-C lenses shouldn't be completely written off.

With regards to this lens, I check and it is a full frame lens so you are good to go!

With regards to your choice of adapter. I've personally used the Fotodoix adapter and it works fine. Sure you won't get the extra stops of brightness as you would with the Metabones speedbooster, but its a good low-cost alternative.

Image stabilization. This lens has IS which means that you can turn off IS in the camera and use the built in lens IS, OR you can manually set the zoom distance (mm) in the IS settings of the camera and turn off IS on the lens. The latter can be a pain because every time you adjust the zoom you have to change the mm setting in the camera, but you can always use a custom key to shortcut to it.